# Should the pin tag be disambiguated? To what?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The tag [pin](/questions/tagged/pin) has several meanings; at least:

- A PIN, i.e. a sequence of digits typically used as a password (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792482/php-client-pin-security) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189816/can-the-net-clickonce-downloader-pull-files-from-a-site-protected-by-a-pin-requ)) → [pin-entry](/questions/tagged/pin-entry) (new) when it's about typing a PIN, and [password](/questions/tagged/password) when it's about storing one
- a pin indicating a position on a map (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478840/google-maps-api-drop-a-new-pin) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139222/is-it-possible-to-call-animatesdrop-in-a-mkannotationview-rather-than-mkpinannot)) → [map-pin](/questions/tagged/map-pin) (new), or just [pin](/questions/tagged/pin)?
- to pin a UI element, meaning to make in inamovible or to make its position fixed (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840456/get-list-of-links-pinned-to-the-taskbar) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872103/pin-lnk-file-to-windows-7-taskbar-using-c-sharp)) → [pinning](/questions/tagged/pinning) (already exists)

I propose to retag as above to disambiguate the tag. Are there other meanings of the tag? Should we disambiguate differently?

Comment: For the record, the [tag:pin] tag is now pining for the fjords.