# Very bad tag "pin"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the pin tag be disambiguated? To what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134384/should-the-pin-tag-be-disambiguated-to-what)

I noticed that the the tag [pin](/questions/tagged/pin) on SO is a horrible mess. As I write this, the top four questions on its "tagged" list use the tag in four completely different ways:

- [Some kind of CPU emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833571/c-and-pin-tool-very-weird-double-variable-issue-with-if-statement)
- [Working with the Pinterest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750834/pinterest-image-zoom-effect)
- [Personal Identification Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737882/requiring-a-pin-to-login-with-symfony2)
- [Pins on iPhone maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685537/mkmapview-mkannotationview-issue)

Aside from sense #3, I can't see where any of these could be considered a valid tag. I wouldn't even know where to begin to fix this. Suggestions?

Comment: There are 121 questions using pin. Looks not that hard if we made it a team effort.

Comment: Well, but I am not sure what the right thing to do would be. Just delete it everywhere? Delete it everywhere except sense #3? Something else?

Comment: But first, we must decide which one to use of course.

Comment: Definitively, [tag:pin] for Pinterest API is a bad choice. _Pin_ is surely not universally known as short for Pinterest API.

Comment: My vote is for complete removal.  I've already removed 25 or so [pin] tags, and closed a few questions in that tag.  If a few people can pile-on, we can get this done quickly.

Comment: Nice work folks, there are zero questions tagged [tag:pin] now!